# Reversible permutations algorithm

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Which algorithm for permutation of list is predictable?

For example, i can get number of i-th permutation

(Haskell code)

```
--List of all possible permutations
permut [] = [[]]
permut xs = [x:ys|x<-xs,ys<-permut (delete x xs)]

--In command line call:
> permut "abc" !! 2
"bac"
```

but i don't know how to reverse it.
I want to o something like this:

```
> getNumOfPermut "abc" "bac"
2
```

Any reversible algorithm goes!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641772/haskell-function-for-finding-letter-number

Comment: What thoughts have you had about how to tackle this? Where did they go wrong?

Comment: Sorry @raymonad . I should write when I posted question that not really any algorithm goes. It must be fast. Searching upon brute force is **not** fast. (And in question, permut use lazy "brute force" and works fine... but aybe also not very good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I wanted to wait until you answered my question about what you had tried, but I had so much fun working out the answer that I just had to write it up and share it. Nerd sniping, I guess! I'm sure I'm not the first to have invented the algorithm below, but I hope you enjoy the presentation.

Our first step is to give an actual runnable implementation of `permut` (which you have not done). Our implementation strategy will be a simple one: choose some element of the list, choose some permutation of the remaining elements, and concatenate the two.

```
chooseFrom [] = []
chooseFrom (x:xs) = (x,xs) : [(y, x:ys) | (y, ys) <- chooseFrom xs]

permut [] = [[]]
permut xs = do
    (element, remaining) <- chooseFrom xs
    permutation <- permut remaining
    return (element:permutation)
```

If we run this on a sample list, it's pretty clear how it behaves:

```
> permut [1..4]
[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,3,2],[0,2,1,3],[0,2,3,1],[0,3,1,2],[0,3,2,1],[1,0,2,3],[1,0,3,2],[1,2,0,3],[1,2,3,0],[1,3,0,2],[1,3,2,0],[2,0,1,3],[2,0,3,1],[2,1,0,3],[2,1,3,0],[2,3,0,1],[2,3,1,0],[3,0,1,2],[3,0,2,1],[3,1,0,2],[3,1,2,0],[3,2,0,1],[3,2,1,0]]
```

The result has a lot of structure; for example, if we group by the first element of the contained lists, there are four groups, each containing 6 (which is 3!) elements:

```
> mapM_ print $ groupBy ((==) `on` head) it
[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,3,2],[0,2,1,3],[0,2,3,1],[0,3,1,2],[0,3,2,1]]
[[1,0,2,3],[1,0,3,2],[1,2,0,3],[1,2,3,0],[1,3,0,2],[1,3,2,0]]
[[2,0,1,3],[2,0,3,1],[2,1,0,3],[2,1,3,0],[2,3,0,1],[2,3,1,0]]
[[3,0,1,2],[3,0,2,1],[3,1,0,2],[3,1,2,0],[3,2,0,1],[3,2,1,0]]
```

So! The first digit of the list tells us "how many 6s to add". Additionally, each list in the above grouping exhibits similar structure: the lists in the first group have three groups of 2! elements each containing `1`, `2`, and `3` as their second element; the lists in each of those groups have 2 groups of 1! elements each starting with each of the remaining digits; and each of *those* groups have 1 group(s) of 0! elements each starting with the only remaining digit. So the second digit tells us "how many 2s to add", the third digit tells us "how many 1s to add", and the last digit tells us "how many 1s to add" (but always tells us to add 0 1s).

If you have implemented a change-of-base function on numbers before (e.g. decimal to hexadecimal or similar) you may recognize this pattern. Indeed, we can treat this as a change-of-base operation with a sliding base: instead of 1s, 10s, 100s, 1000s, and so on columns, we have 0!s, 1!s, 2!s, 3!s, 4!s, and so on columns. Let's write it! For efficiency, we'll compute all the sliding bases up front with a `factorials` function.

```
import Data.List

factorials n = scanr (*) 1 [n,n-1..1]
deleteAt i xs = case splitAt i xs of (b, e) -> b ++ drop 1 e

permutIndices permutation original
    = go (factorials (length permutation - 1))
         permutation
         original
    where
    go _ [] [] = [0]
    go _ [] _  = []
    go _ _  [] = []
    go (base:bases) (x:xs) ys = do
        i <- elemIndices x ys
        remainder <- go bases xs (deleteAt i ys)
        return (i*base + remainder)
    go [] _ _ = error "the impossible happened!"
```

Here's a sample sanity-check:

```
> map (`permutIndices` [1..4]) (permut [1..4])
[[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]]
```

And, for fun, here you can see it handling ambiguity correctly:

```
> permutIndices "acbba" "aabbc"
[21,23,45,47]
> map (permut "aabbc"!!) it
["acbba","acbba","acbba","acbba"]
```

...and showing that it's significantly more efficient than `elemIndices`:

```
> :set +s
> elemIndices "zyxwvutsr" (permut "rstuvwxyz")
[362879]
(2.65 secs, 1288004848 bytes)
> permutIndices "zyxwvutsr" "rstuvwxyz"
[362879]
(0.00 secs, 1030304 bytes)
```

Less than one thousandth the allocation/time. Seems like a win!

Comment: I'm sorry @DanielWagner , but your solution is not compiling for some reason. Please review your code.

Answer (score 1):

So, to be clear, you are looking for a way to find the position of a given permution-

```
"bac"
```

in a list of given permutions-

```
["abc", "acb", "bac", ....]
```

This problem actually has nothing inherently to do with permutions themselves.  You want to find the location of an element in an array.

As @raymonad mentioned in his comment, stackoverflow.com/questions/20641772/ deals with this question, and the answer there was, use `elemIndex`.

```
elemIndex thePermutionToFind $ permut theString
```

Keep in mind, that if letters repeat, a value might appear more than once in the output, if your "permut" function doesn't remove these duplicates (ie- Note that permut "aa" = ["aa", "aa"])....  In this case the elemIndices function will come in useful.

If elemIndex returns `Nothing`, it means the string you supplied wasn't a permution.

(this isn't the most effecient algorithm for large strings, since the number of permutions grows like the factorial of the size of the string....  Which is worse than exponential.)

Comment: I don't think this answer is fair. While it's true that `elemIndex` is _correct_, it's certainly not in the spirit of the question. We know a lot of structure about the list in question that `elemIndex` is refusing to exploit.

Comment: @DanielWagner- I actually agree with you....  That is why I went back and put in the performance comment after the fact. (Just to be clear, my answer is technically correct, it just doesn't scale....)