# Haskell function for finding letter number

Tags: string, list, haskell

Does Haskell have a function that lets you find the number of a particular element of a word i.e. [char] so the element number of 'F' in "FROG" is 0. Also, what about words where that letter appears more than once, can this function return a list of letter positions i.e. 'E' in "TEETER" would be [1,2,4]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two functions you're looking for are in `Data.List`, they are `elemIndex` and `elemIndices`.

```
elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int


λ> elemIndex 'F' "FROG"
Just 0
λ> elemIndices 'E' "TEETER"
[1,2,4]
```

When looking for something like this it's often helpful to write down the type you want and then (if possible) generalize it.  You can often find things in the standard library this way.

Comment: It is worth noting that these two functions are the [second and third results on hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+String+-%3E+Char+-%3E+Int) for even a rough (incorrect) guess at the type.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson pretty good, although it is interesting that it prioritizes `throwErrnoPath` above the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Type this into hoogle

```
[a]->a->Int
```

and see this

```
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

edit-

I missed the second part of your question....  But an analagous hoogle search works for that also.